# Command `/bin/sh -c ls -lh` doesn't show the output as a list

Tags: bash, shell, ls

Running command `/bin/sh -c ls`, I see:

```
> /bin/sh -c ls
 20190816_212056.png                                                Opera_65.0.3467.78_Setup.exe
 20190816_212219.png                                                Opera_66.0.3515.27_Setup.exe
 20190816_212344.png                                                opera-stable_60.0.3255.95_amd64.rpm
 20191112_134658.jpg                                                opera-stable_62.0.3331.99_amd64.rpm
 20200201_175524.jpg                                                opera-stable_63.0.3368.107_amd64.rpm
 20200201_175602.jpg                                                opera-stable_65.0.3467.48_amd64.rpm
```

When I run `/bin/sh -c ls -lh`, I see the exact same output as `/bin/sh -c ls`. The option `-lh` is not considered at all. Why is that? Am I missing something?

#### Note

`/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `bash`:

```
> ls -lh /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 20  2019 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a command with spaces inside you need to add "" around it. Otherwise it will just execute `ls`

Try running
`/bin/sh -c "ls -lh"`

Comment: So, why I see Docker executing `/bin/sh -c` commands with spaces? Is Docker different?

Comment: @user3405291 whatever log you're looking at probably just prints the arguments as is, without quoting or otherwise indicating separate arguments.